# libcurl - multi_socket - how it Working + directly IOCP?

Tags: c, libcurl

I have an implemented interface based IO Completion Ports Windows - I want to try and use it together with libcurl.

The online book curl says that:

> There are numerous event based systems to select from out there, and
> libcurl is completely agnostic to which one you use. libevent, libev
> and libuv are three popular ones but **you can also go directly** to your
> operating system's native solutions such as epoll, kqueue, /dev/poll,
> pollset, Event Completion or **I/O Completion Ports**.

I am reading online Curl book chapter on multi socket: ["multi_socket" interface](https://everything.curl.dev/libcurl/drive/multi-socket)

It says:

> libcurl informs the application about socket activity to wait for with
> a callback called CURLMOPT_SOCKETFUNCTION. Your application needs to
> implement such a function:
>
> Using this, libcurl will set and remove sockets your application
> should monitor. Your application tells the underlying event-based
> system to wait for the sockets. This callback will be called multiple
> times if there are multiple sockets to wait for, and it will be called
> again when the status changes and perhaps you should switch from
> waiting for a writable socket to instead wait for it to become
> readable.

The devil himself can't figure out how it works.

-For example:

-Created completion port: CreateIoCompletionPort ()

-Created completion port handler: GetQueuedCompletionStatus ()

-Created a windows asynchronous socket: WSASocket ()

-filled in all the necessary structures like - sockadrr

-Connected to remote server: WSAConnect ()

-Linked socket to the IO Completion Port.

-Called the WSASend () and send to server message.

-Now I want libcurl to read the message from the server and do all the necessary actions, but I absolutely cannot understand from the description how ???

> libcurl informs the application about socket activity to wait for with
> a callback called CURLMOPT_SOCKETFUNCTION.

How is this call -back function called? Who will call her? Where ? why and why ?? I do not understand (((((

Please, help :(

Comment: Have you seen this: https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLMOPT_SOCKETFUNCTION.html ?

Comment: @Morten Jensen, for what purpose are you asking?

Comment: All callbacks are called when you call curl_\*_perform() or curl_\*_socket_action().

Comment: @S.M., thank you! But there is one problem - in the documentation for
socket_action() - talking about "curl_socket_t sockfd", but the documentation does not say at all what it is and where can I get this ---> curl_socket_t sockfd.

Comment: How you can't get it? You have curl.h. curl_socket_t is a platform independent name for platform dependent socket descriptors, SOCKET for Windows, int for others.

Comment: @S.M., the problem is that Windows also has SOCKET, but together with IOСP, not SOCKET is used, but WSASocket used. That is, there are two types of sockets in Windows - standard blocking SOCKETs and non-blocking asynchronous WSASockets.

Comment: @S.M.,That is, when I call curl_multi_socket_action (), I can pass my WSASocket to the curl_multi_socket_action () function?

Comment: I do not get what you mean. WSASocket is a masked function WSASocketA or WSASocketW, not a type.

Comment: @S.M., what's the difference WSASocketA/WSASocketW or masked WSASocket. WSASocket != Socket. That is, when I call curl_multi_socket_action (), I can pass my WSASocket to the curl_multi_socket_action () function? In Curl.h ----> typedef SOCKET curl_socket_t for (CURL_WIN32).   How you can't get it?

Comment: @S.M., That is, the book says that Libcurl CAN be used together with IOCP, but in Curl.h - typedef SOCKET curl_socket_t, and IOCP ONLY WSASocket is used, and not just SOCKET. You understand ?

Comment: I checked all the .c and .h libcurl files - they don't have a single line of code that mentions the name - WSASocket/WSASocketA/WSASocketW.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240388/discussion-between-s-m-and-optimus1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it turned out - that Libcurl multi_socket mode cannot work with Windows IOCP.